# Share Files via Link option is not available in my salesforce org

Tags: permissions

[image]
Share Files via Link option is not available in my salesforce org. Kindly help me out. 
Also I could not find Content Deliveries option in Setup.

[image]

Comment: Wonder if you should be raising this with Salesforce Support as this is a feature in all editions.

Comment: Okay, I have logged a case with SF.